# Finding a Range in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

I understand how to define an array range in CoffeeScript

```
lng[1..10]
```

However if I have

```
data = 10
```

What's the best way to find if 10 is within a range of 1 and 11?

```
if data is between(1..11)
  return true
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no "between" keyword, but you can utilize a normal array-range:

```
if data in [1..11]
    alert 'yay'
```

But that's a bit of an overkill, so in simple cases I'd recommend a normal comparison:

```
if 1 <= data <= 11
    alert 'yay'
```

Comment: thats great, I did think of doing that by didn't know if there was a ruby like call of between? - thanks!!

Comment: +1, with chained comparison operators in CoffeeScript it becomes very readable =D

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind polluting the native prototypes, you can add a `between` method to the `Number` objects:

```
Number::between = (min, max) -> 
  min <= this <= max

if 10.between(1, 11)
  alert 'yay'
```

Although i personally wouldn't use it. `if 1 <= something <= 11` is more direct and everyone will understand it. The `between` method, instead, has to be looked up if you want to know what it does (or you'd have to guess), and i think it doesn't add that much.